# Finding a single element in postgres json array

Tags: sql, arrays, json, postgresql

I have a table that has a Json typed column and I am trying query that table based of values that are contained in that json column.

Here is the relevant DDL:

```
create table user
(
    roles json
);
```

Here is what a roles value would look like:

```
[70,254]
```

I want to be able to perform a query like this:

```
select * from user where roles in(254);
```

So I've tried this:

```
SELECT * from apptree.atf_app_user where roles @> 254;
```

And it is giving me this error:

```
[2017-12-01 14:58:16] [42883] ERROR: operator does not exist: json @> integer
[2017-12-01 14:58:16] Hint: No operator matches the given name and argument type(s). You might need to add explicit type casts.
[2017-12-01 14:58:16] Position: 48
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The operator [@> works on jsonb arguments.](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/functions-json.html) Cast the column to jsonb:

```
select * 
from apptree.atf_app_user 
where roles::jsonb @> '254';
```

Update. There is no operator to search in a json array for any of multiple values. You can use the function `json_array_elements_text(),` e.g.:

```
select t.* 
from apptree.atf_app_user t
cross join json_array_elements_text(roles)
where value in ('70', '71');
```

Comment: Thank you so much, I have been stuck on that forever.

Comment: is it expensive to cast the column or does it slow the query down very much?

Comment: The cost is not great, however using jsonb (instead of json) is generally more efficient in most cases. In your case it may be worth changing the column type to jsonb.

Comment: That would be a large code base refactor, I think we will do that, just not in the short term. One more question: How would I search in an array for more that one value?